# Почему запрос к Google Calendar API выбрасывает 403 ошибку при создании события?

Tags: java, spring, google-calendar-api

Пытаюсь добавлять события в календарь при помощи Google API. Зарегистрировал приложение в Google Cloud, создал OAuth2.0 Credentials, запросил доступ на создание событий и изменение/просмотр календарей, реализовал авторизацию и получение токена. Методы просмотра календарей и событий отрабатывают, но метод добавления события выбрасывает ошибку 403:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "forbidden"
}
],
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}
```

Не понимаю, что я делаю не так. Как я должен передавать сервису ключ API?
Сейчас код выглядит так:

**Получение информации о клиенте:**

```
private OAuth2AuthorizedClient loadClientInfo(OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) throws Exception {
    try {
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClientService
            .loadAuthorizedClient(
                authentication.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
                authentication.getName());
        return client;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Вызов метода добавления события:**

```
@GetMapping("/addEvent")
public Event addEvent(OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = loadClientInfo(authentication);
    return googleService.addEvent(client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
}
```

**Добавление события:**

```
public Event addEvent(String tokenValue) throws IOException {
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(tokenValue);

        Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
        
        // Создание события для отправки...

        // Отправка
        return service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`The request is missing a valid API key.`

Не буду утверждать наверняка, но Calendar API не новый. А для INSERT методов всегда надо было поставлять API ключ даже для авторизованного пользователя, т.к. система не умела считать запросы иначе<sup>*****</sup>.

Ну, как бы новой версии API я не вижу. Следовательно, создайте тут же в проекте ключ и отправляйте его вместе с урлом добавления записей

```
https://бла-бла-бла/?key=API_KEY
```

---

<sup>* - Чисто сугубо мое индивидуальное мнение</sup>

Comment: Да, в ключе и было дело, но я не понимал, как добавить этот ключ не напрямую в URL. Т.к. у Гугла же есть класс Calendar с методами внесений изменений в календарь и т.д.. Но я так и не понял и переписал все методы через OkHttp. :(